# Group HomeKit automatons by topic

Tags: ios, automation, homekit

I am new to HomeKit and wanted to create my first automations.

I have an Eve Energy Smart Plug that should be turned on and off like this:

| Day of the week | On | Off |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mon-Thu | 5 AM | 10 PM |
| Fri | 5 AM | 11:59 PM |
| Sat | 7 AM | 11:59 PM |
| Sun | 8 AM | 10 PM |

Everything works perfectly fine.

But I have five automation rules.

I got another use case where another smart plug should be turned on and off on a more complex schedule. This would be about another seven rules. That is pretty confusing, having so many rules, all ordered by time not considering the weekday in the ordering.

I can not imagine having maybe a dozen devices with 50+ rules.

Is it possible to group the rules by topic or in some kind of folder? I would be grateful if someone can help.

(Using iOS 16.5)